# Swift - conversion of string to expression

Tags: string, expression

I am working on an application in which simple mathematical expressions are passed around as strings (for example "2+3"). I need to execute these expressions to make sure they equal a target.

In Mathematica / Wolfram Language, one can convert strings to expressions with the simple command ToExpression[]. Is there anything equivalent in Swift? If not, how might one convert the string into workable math?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `[NSExpression][1]`, like this...

```
let expression = NSExpression(format:"2+3")
if let result = expression.expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil) as? NSNumber {
  print(result)
} else {
  print("error evaluating expression")
}
```

Here's a good [blog post from NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/) on using NSExpression (includes Swift examples).

Comment: that's exactly what I needed. In an extension to my original question, is there a mechanism for extracting the operators and operands from the expression? So for example, to extract (2,3,3) and (+,/) from "2+3/3"?

Comment: never mind my last question -- the answer to that one is in componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet()